# how to change the name of custom facebook page tab?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I created a custom page tab in facebook. now i want to change the name of the page tab. 
the code i am using right now is:

```
$facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/tabs/', 'POST', array('access_token' => $access_token, 'app_id' => $appId,    'position' => 2, 'custom_name' => $tab_name, 'is_non_connection_landing_tab' => true ));
```

i even tried this code as well:
    $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/tabs/app_'.$appId.'', 'POST', array('access_token' => $access_token,'position' => 2, 'custom_name' => $tab_name, 'is_non_connection_landing_tab' => true ));

Answer (score 0):

In order to rename or rearrange a tab, you need to do the following:

```
$facebook->api( '/'.$page_id.'/tabs/app_' . $app_id , 'POST', array( 
  'access_token' => $page_access_token, 
  'position' => 2,
  'custom_name' => $tab_name
));
```

You must use the Page `access_token` to make changes to the application, a user `access_token` won't work.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i tried that one as well but didnot solve my problem. do i need to review my app before i get to access my manage_page permission??

Comment: You will be able to use the permission as a developer / admin before it's approved, but other users won't be able to use it without approval.